# Is hackerrank useful as a screening tool?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

This question may well be too subjective for SE, but I'm going to try. Help me make it more focused and objective if possible.

I'm writing from the perspective of a job candidate, but I'm interested in answers from either side of the fence.

In the last 3 months, I've been applying for a very large number of jobs. Many of the companies (probably the best of them) have asked me to complete some form of programming assignment. Some were timed, some were live, some were open-ended. Two of the timed ones used hackerrank.

As a job candidate, my experience with hackerrank has been abysmal. I utterly failed the hackerrank tests--not because I got the answers wrong, but because the time ran out before I even figured out how to use the !@#$ interface, what input format was being fed to my subroutine, and where STDERR went, etc.

Compare this to my non-hackerrank tests, and I've been very well received by job recruiters. Google flew me to Mountain View (ultimately they didn't offer me a job, though), and multiple other companies have said they liked my coding, and to date, 3 others (not counting Google) have invited me for on-site interviews.

So I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't simply that my "code test taking" ability isn't there.

Back to hackerrank. I'm sure that I could solve my problems with hackerrank if I spent sufficient time just using the site and learning its nuances, expectations and bugs.

So my question is, is hackerrank actually useful as a job recruiting tool?

As a job candidate, is it worth it to learn the system? Or should I consider hackerrank tests the same way I would consider a large number of IT certifications: GIGO. (And by extension, I likely don't want to work for a company that uses it as a criteria, even if I did pass.)

As a job recruiter, is it valuable? Does it truly filter out "bad" candidates? Or does it filter out good candidates who just don't test well because they haven't spent the requisite hours learning hackerrank?

Comment: Well, their editor is locking up in Chrome, which is enough to make _me_ write them off as irrelevant... (Cute concept. I presume they're hoping to sell lists of pre-screened applicants. But I can immediately see about 6 ways to game their system...)

Comment: Ask your recruiters. Don't ask us.

Comment: Ask three recruiters, get four answers.  Voting to close as primarily opinion based!

Comment: Anecdotally: I got a job after completing a hackerrank test. Didn't like it. Leaving next week. And yeah, the site itself was the biggest problem - if I hadn't pre-prepared, I wouldn't have been able to figure out how to do the test in time. Despite all this, I'm not sure this could be made non-subjective, and/or anything but a hacker rank bashing post, so voting to close.

Comment: @yochannah: Why didn't you like it? Is your reason for leaving in any way related to or predictable by their use of hackerrank?

Comment: it's relatively unrelated, I think. If anything, I'd add say that testing coding ability before joining a company - any coding tests that check ability, rather than memorising trivia - is a good thing, but in my case it was misleading as it implied I'd do a lot of coding in the job - which I wasn't expected to. :/

Comment: @yochannah: I agree coding tests are valuable in general.  Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is, is hackerrank actually useful as a job recruiting tool?

Regardless of what we think, the question you need to answer is: *do recruiters that offer jobs you want use it?* If so, that's the hoop you have to jump through to get the job. Just another part of the application process you may or may not like. Like the dress code for the on site interview.

Comment: Indeed. It's two sides to the same coin.  That's why I've asked about both sides of the issue in my question. This feels to me like a simple re-statement of the question, rather than an answer.